# Can anyone recommend me any literature that discusses the advantages/pitfalls of using proxy measures and additive indices?

Tags: methodology

Trying to find some literature on the topic (especially as it pertains to social science research) to increase my theoretical understanding. Any recommendations will be much appreciated. Thanks!